# .NET CORE GRPC stream exception

Tags: .net-core, grpc-c#

I'm working on a .NET Core  chat room using gRPC (BI Directional streaming).
client, for now,  is a console app (.net core 3.1, server is 5.0).
client-server communication was working alright and suddenly, I started having RpcExceptions thrown.
the problem is, the exceptions thrown have StatusCode=OK and no details.
here is a code sample (simplified)

**SERVER Stream RPC**

```
if (!await requestStream.MoveNext())
                return;
//Open Connection - set user stream to server's output
client.Stream = responseStream;

while(await requestStream.MoveNext())
{
    var chatMessage = requestStream.Current;
    chatMessage.Msg = $"{requestStream.Current.ClientName}: {requestStream.Current.Msg}";
    foreach (var user in loggedClients)
    {
        user.Stream.WriteAsync(chatMessage);
    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
using (var streaming = client.RPC_BroadcastChatMessage(metaData))
{
    //Read stream and display on console
    var readTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (await streaming.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{streaming.ResponseStream.Current.Msg}");
        }
    });

    //Send first message (empty string) - for a welcome message
    Console.WriteLine("Sending empty msg");
    await streaming.RequestStream.WriteAsync(emptyMsg);

    //Wait for messages from user and send to server
    Console.WriteLine("Type message and press Enter to send...");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();   
 
    while (!string.Equals(line, "exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var stream = streaming.RequestStream;
                    
        var msg = new ChatMessage()
        {              
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientName = $"User{userNumber}",
            Msg = line,
            RoomId = roomId
        };
                    
        await stream.WriteAsync(msg);

        line = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Exception**
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="OK", Detail="")

both client and server run locally.
I've tried googling the exception but haven't found anything yet (not statusCode=OK related, anyways).
does anyone has any leads? I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same issue, server is implemented in c++, client is in .NET 5.
The connection works fine most of the time, but after a longer period of time the .NET client write fails with the same exception.
After the exception the conncetion seems to hang as no more messages are read by the client